# AutoMapper error mapping types with type converters

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper

I am getting an error while running a mapper class. I know the issue is on the url property but I am not sure what might be wrong, been messing with it for awhile now.

The only thing that makes it work is having an ignore on the Url property which defeats the purpose of the UrlResolver.

Using
.NET Core 5
AutoMapper 10.1.1

```
namespace Service.Models
{
    public class Connection<T>
    {
        public Connection() => this.Items = new List<T>();
        public int TotalCount { get; set; }
        public List<T> Items { get; }
    }        

    public class ReadCar
    {
        public int CarId { get; set; }
        public string Make { get; set; } = default!;
        public string Model { get; set; } = default!;
    }
}

namespace Api.Models
{
    public class Connection<T>
    {
        public Connection() => this.Items = new List<T>();
        public int TotalCount { get; set; }
        public List<T> Items { get; }
    }

    public class GetCar
    {
        public int CarId { get; set; }
        public string Make { get; set; } = default!;
        public string Model { get; set; } = default!;
        public Uri Url { get; set; } = default!;
    }
}

public class MainMapperProfile : Profile
{
    public MainMapperProfile()
    {
        _ = this.CreateMap<ReadCar, GetCar>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Url, source => source.MapFrom<UrlResolver, int>(src => src.CarId));
        _ = this.CreateMap(typeof(Service.Models.Connection<>), typeof(Api.Models.Connection<>));
    }
}

public class UrlResolver : IMemberValueResolver<object, object, int, Uri>
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor;
    private readonly LinkGenerator linkGenerator;

    public UrlResolver(
        IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor,
        LinkGenerator linkGenerator)
    {
        this.httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        this.linkGenerator = linkGenerator;
    }

    public Uri Resolve(object source, object destination, int sourceMember, Uri destMember, ResolutionContext context)
        => new(this.linkGenerator.GetUriByRouteValues(
            this.httpContextAccessor.HttpContext!,
            "ControllerName",
            sourceMember)!);
}

public class GetCarPageCommand
{
    public GetCarPageCommand(
        IMapper mapper,
        ICarService carService)
    {
        this.mapper = mapper;
        this.carService = carService;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var cars = await this.carService.ReadPageAsync(1, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
        var connection = this.mapper.Map<Api.Models.Connection<Api.Models.GetCar>>(cars);
    }
```

Here is the complete error I get

```
AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Error mapping types.

Mapping types:
Connection`1 -> Connection`1
Building.DataModels.Connection`1[[Service.Models.ReadCar, Service.Models, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]
-> Building.Api.Models.Connection`1[[Api.Models.GetCar, Api.Models, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]

Type Map configuration:
Connection`1 -> Connection`1
Building.DataModels.Connection`1[[Service.Models.ReadCar, Service.Models, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]
-> Building.Api.Models.Connection`1[[Api.Models.GetCar, Api.Models, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]

Destination Member:
Items

---> AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Error mapping types.

Mapping types:
ReadCar -> GetCar
Service.Models.ReadCar -> Api.Models.GetCar

Type Map configuration:
ReadCar -> GetCar
Service.Models.ReadCar -> Api.Models.GetCar

Destination Member:
Url

---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'uriString')
   at System.Uri..ctor(String uriString)
   at Api.MapperProfiles.UrlResolver.Resolve(Object source, Object destination, Int32 sourceMember, Uri destMember, ResolutionContext context) in C:\App\MapperProfiles\UrlResolver.cs:line 23
   at lambda_method28(Closure , Object , Connection`1 , ResolutionContext )
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at lambda_method28(Closure , Object , Connection`1 , ResolutionContext )
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at lambda_method28(Closure , Object , Connection`1 , ResolutionContext )
   at Api.Commands.Cars.GetCarPageCommand.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\App\Commands\Cars\GetCarPageCommand.cs:line 15
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Logged|12_1(ControllerActionInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Extensions.MapWhenMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Serilog.AspNetCore.RequestLoggingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Comment: Please tag line UrlResolver.cs:line 23 in your code sample so we can identify it. According to the stacktrace there is no problem with AutoMapper setup just your ````UrlResolver.Resolve```` tries to instantiate an ````Uri```` with null parameter value at the mentioned line.

Comment: Line 23 is `=> new(this.linkGenerator.GetUriByRouteValues()`. But I don't see any parameter null while debugging. If I map `var car = this.mapper.Map<Api.Models.GetCar>>(cars);` then it works just fine.

Comment: According to exception the whole parameter of ````new(...)```` call evaluates to null despite the parts of it (e.g. ````sourceMember````) can be not null. Try to rewrite line 23 using legacy, multiline method syntax and check the new line number in stacktrace. Maybe it points out what is wrong.